# Creating tabs using Bootstrap and angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to run  a sample code, with ui.bootstrap.tabs using Bootstrap and angular.js . The html code is in aspx and I use .net framework 3.5

The example.js has:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.tabs = [
{ title: 'Dynamic Title 1', content: 'Dynamic content 1' },
{ title: 'Dynamic Title 2', content: 'Dynamic content 2', disabled: true }
```

];

```
$scope.alertMe = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('You\'ve selected the alert tab!');
    });
};
```

});

The HTML part:

```
 <link href="css/bs/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
  Select a tab by setting active binding to true:

<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="tabs[0].active = true">Select second   
 tab</button>

   <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="tabs[1].active = true">Select third
   tab</button>

<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="tabs[1].disabled = ! tabs[1].disabled">Enable /
 Disable third tab</button>


<script src="jsNew/example.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js" type ="text/javascript">  

 <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.js" type ="text/javascript">
```

When I run I get the error Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'angular' is undefined pointing on the first line of example.js . Please could some one help, which directive I am missing. Or could some one give me a sample . I just want to create tabs using bootstrap and angularjs.Not worked on  angular  and bootstrap . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You included angular *after* your example.js, so angular isn't defined when you try to use it. You need to include all your dependencies in order, and make sure you close your script tags. Move example.js below angular and you should be good to go!

```
<script src="jsNew/example.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Should be:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jsNew/example.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: example.js is another file and in the html part I have included it using script src.

Comment: I know, but you include it above the angular include. Edited my answer for clarity